# Confirmation to Save before Closing Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I came across some vba code online which forces users to enable macros. It displays only "Sheet1" when macros are turned off and when they are turned on it hides "Sheet1" and unhides the working sheets. This is a very ingenious code but there is one drawback. When I close the file it doesn't ask me if I want to save the file or not. It automatically saves itself so as to keep the rest of the sheets hidden. I would like to know if there is a way to get around this, that is if I could enable the "save/ close without saving" prompt and also keep the sheets hidden except for "Sheet1"

Below is the code:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

'Step 1: Declare your variables
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Step 2: Unhide the Starting Sheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = xlSheetVisible

'Step 3: Start looping through all worksheets
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

'Step 4: Check each worksheet name
If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then

'Step 5: Hide the sheet
ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
End If

'Step 6: Loop to next worksheet
Next ws


'Step 7: Save the workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Step 1: Declare your variables
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Step 2: Start looping through all worksheets
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

'Step 3: Unhide All Worksheets
ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible

'Step 4: Loop to next worksheet
Next ws


'Step 5: Hide the Start Sheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = xlVeryHidden

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to mention about the method to force the users to enable macros: While this would work for most regular users, it's very easy for the user to simply unhide the rest of the sheets one way or another so if the intention is simply improved usability then it's good, but otherwise as a security / copy-protection measure, it might leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: Nothing about this code does anything to force users to enable macros, it simply prompts them to enable because of the workbook-level events (a normal procedure in a standard module will alert in the menu bar instead of the pop-up). They can still opt to keep macros disabled at the prompt.  I am revising the title of this post, accordingly.

Comment: n/m, it looks like someone else already revised question title :)

Comment: Hi David,

u are wrong. this code does force users to enable macros. We have to have Sheet1 with the message "Please enable macros to view the file". Unless the user doesn't enable macros he is unable to view hidden worksheets.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `ActiveWorkbook.Save` with your own message like so:

```
If MsgBox("Would you like to save?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Save Workbook") = vbYes Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End If
```

Comment: no this won't work. If the user decides to not save the workbook. the sheets won't be hidden when the workbook is opened again.

Comment: In which case, this doesn't make sense to me. For the workbook to keep the sheets hidden when a user next opens, you'd not want to give the user an option to save and simple save it as you already are. What is the actual issue?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention, my bad. the problem is if a user casually or erroneously enters some text the changes get saved when the user unknowingly clicks on close (thinking he might get a prompt) even though he doesn't actually save the file.

Comment: In which case, could enforce some worksheet cell protection to disable any changes from being made to the sheets?

Comment: no I want the users to modify the file. I don't want them to enter incorrect text. we all have a tendency of entering text and closing the file thinking we would get a prompt asking whether we want to save the file or not. I want to avoid such a situation. The file when saved sends an email to many recipients.

Comment: replace the last line of the workbook_beforeclose with `activeworkbook.saved=false`. This way any changes will trigger excel to ask you to save, and if no change it won't ask.